# How to store strings for a Hangman game in android?

Tags: android, database, string

I am trying to develop a hangman application in android.I want to have a string selected as a question from a list of categories like places,animals,sports,etc.Each category should contain a list of strings.Should I store the categories in a database or create an arraylist/array for each category?Is it possible to store the categories in xml and is it recommended?

Thanks in advance

Comment: database is by far best solution, because its really fast and flexible. also very easy to query.

Comment: may be you can store the data in a csv file in the assets folder and read the file at the launch time and keep the words in array or list... if the number of entries are very big then as @MarkoNiciforovic said it makes sense to save them in DB to avoid using lot of memory for storing the list of string...

using csv would also help is updating the game with new values by replacing or updating the csv file...

Comment: how many strings would mean very big? @PrafulBhatnagar

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should use database because its really faster than any other solution and more flexible. You can also query it very easy. Also I guess you would want to store many values which database is good for, memory stuffs.  If you are not familiar with databases, check out this link http://learnandroid.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-database.html. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

> .Should I store the categories in a database or create an arraylist/array for each category?Is it possible to store the categories in xml and is it recommended?

Please use a database. The DB will let you wrap your queries in a transaction and perform updates on the model using the `onUpgrade()` method call. You don't get these features with a XML.